# How to enable Speakerphone on android through adb shell?

Tags: android, adb, phone-call, speakerphone

I am working on a testing tool and I am able to initiate and terminate voice call from default Dialer app in android using following commands.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:+919999999999

adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENDCALL
```

I need to enable Speakerphone through adb interface after initiating voice call. How can I achieve this? My android device may not have root permission.

Comment: I know that I can use "adb shell input keyevent" to navigate the UI and then select appropriate UI "Speakerphone" button. This solution will be application dependent and will change for every device and dialer application. I am looking for some generalized solution that can work on different android devices.